# Dynamics AX - Apply range on combobox datasource / items

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, ax

I just want to limit the records brought in the combobox based on some condition, say like which menu item opened the form. So specific rows should return.

I have no idea about the code, also tell which method/event to use, field's modified method, control's lookup ? or at Datasource ? Form or class ? which place among these are best for it?

Answer (score 1):

Ax does not have a combobox where the list is based on a datasource - so find the code that uses table data to fill a combobox list and add your limit there.

I could provide a more specific answer if you described how your combobox is filled or what you mean by *list* of comboboxes or its *current value*

1. Does that combobox have the Extended Data Type or Base Enum properties filled?
   If any of these properties are filled, find the associated baseEnum.
2. Search the form for the combobox name - was it mentioned
   there?

If the combobox is filled automatically using an associated base enum, you can either create your own base enum or write code from scratch using the `add` method.

Or just leave it as it is and add an error message where code uses a wrong value.

Read [Axaptapedia article](http://www.axaptapedia.com/FormComboBoxControl)

Comment: exactly thats what i m asking, where i m suppose to look for the combo filling code / query.

The easy straight way would be to add a clause in the query, bus since i am new to this x++ framework, I just dont know where to get these things :D

Comment: 1. Does combobox have Extended Data Type or Base Enum propeties filled? If any of these propeties filled, find associated baseEnum.
2. Search the form for the combobox name - does it have mentioned there? 

Read Axaptapedia article http://www.axaptapedia.com/FormComboBoxControl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [SysFormEnumComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc603045%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) helper class?

For an example see [this link](http://tjaxdynamics.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/hide-enum-values-in-combo-box/).
Or download an example [here](http://kashperuk.blogspot.dk/2008/04/sysformenumcombobox-class-allowing-to.html).